# PHP session always starts when page changes

Tags: php, session

I have a blog website. I can change languages by clicking flags at the top of the website. When I select English or Spanish, the page changes to that language.
However when I click any menu item, the website language reverts to the default language, and doesn't stay in the language I clicked.

I put my chosen language value in Session, however it loses its value when I click another page.

I can see that my session_id() always changing. session always start.

Here is my session test code in homepage

```
ob_start();
if (session_status() == 1) {     //or if(isset($_SESSION)) both of them not work and session_start() command work.
    session start();
    echo 'started';
}
echo " SESSION ID VALUE: ".session_id()."  .Session Status:".session_status();
```

Output: (you will see on website)

> started SESSION ID VALUE:  5d7e8cacfde4bc87f6e55b4fcddd5af7 Session
>   Status2/

My host is godaddy.  I asked them to fix it but they said I developed this codes and they didn't look. I don't know what should I do? I see session_path is /tmp and I write `is_writable(ini_set("session_path"))`  it is readable and writable.

Comment: If you open your browser developer tools and check the Network pane, can you see the session ID cookie header? Is it in both request and response? When does it change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should execute session_start() always. If the session is created then it will use the already created session, else it will create a new one.

Also in session_status you should compare with the PHP constants not hardcoded values.

session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php

Comment: I thought when session_start() command works, new session start and it give new id. so i used session status

Comment: This is valuable information but I can't understand how it answers the question. `PHP_SESSION_NONE` is 1 is all current PHP versions ([demo](https://3v4l.org/SO2Cr)) and original code (no matter how convoluted) does call `session_start()` after all. Why will this work where code in question didn't?

Comment: Hello Alvaro, I am not saying that comparing to the PHP_SESSION_NONE will work, I am just suggesting to use constants instead of hardcoded values.